# How to set Z-buffer in viewport3d

Tags: wpf

I have a 3D Cube on which i have loaded data in the form of multiple Mesh Geometries. Now, i want to display that data according to the Z-Buffer that means visualize intersecting back Mesh Geometries in front.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate? Some images might be of help.

Comment: I have multiple overlapping 3d meshes, And I want to visualize the back mesh in front without changing the z  or its actual location. I tried the EmissiveMaterial but it only works with the black background.